# Different results after changing the order of integration with constant limits (Failure of Fubini's theorem)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, order-of-integration

I have the following question

$I_{1}=\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1}\ \frac{(x-y)}{(x+y)^{3}}\ dy\,dx$

Evaulating the above I get [$I_{1}=0.5$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB%E2%88%AB((x-y)%2F(x%2By)%5E3)dydx,%20x%20from%200%20to%201,%20y%20from%200%20to%201)

Now if I switch the order of integration

$I_{2}=\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1}\ \frac{(x-y)}{(x+y)^{3}}\ dx\,dy$

I get [$I_{2}=-0.5$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB%E2%88%AB((x-y)%2F(x%2By)%5E3)dxdy,%20x%20from%200%20to%201,%20y%20from%200%20to%201)

Why is the value negative after changing the order? Shouldn't the result be same for constant limits (as the region of space is the same for both the integrals) ?

Comment: No. This is an improper integral. You might be careful when interchanging integrations.

Comment: The integrand is such that $f(y,x)=-f(x,y)$.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima The integral $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x-y)\,dx\,dy$ exists despite the fact that $f(x,y)\equiv x-y =-f(y,x)$.  That is not the reason that the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem fails.

Comment: @xbh Thanks. Can you tell me how does an improper integral affect the order of integration for double integrals?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem, in particular the sentence beginning with *If the above integral of the absolute value is not finite, then the two iterated integrals...*

Comment: Thanks @JackD'Aurizio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @[Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44121/jack-daurizio), the answer lies in the below quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Rearranging_a_conditionally_convergent_iterated_integral)

> If the above integral of the absolute value is not finite, then the two iterated integrals may have different values.
>
> ***Failure of Fubini's theorem for non-integrable functions***
>
> Fubini's theorem tells us that (for measurable functions on a product
>   of σ-finite measure spaces) if the integral of the absolute value is
>   finite, then the order of integration does not matter; if we integrate
>   first with respect to x and then with respect to y, we get the same
>   result as if we integrate first with respect to y and then with
>   respect to x. The assumption that the integral of the absolute value
>   is finite is "Lebesgue integrability", and without it the two repeated
>   integrals can have different values.
>
> A simple example to show that the repeated integrals can be different
>   in general is to take the two measure spaces to be the positive
>   integers, and to take the function f(x,y) to be 1 if x=y, −1 if x=y+1,
>   and 0 otherwise. Then the two repeated integrals have different values
>   0 and 1.
>
> Another example is as follows for the function:
>
> ${\displaystyle {\frac {x^{2}-y^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}}=-{\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial x\partial y}}\arctan(y/x).}$
>
> The iterated integrals
>
> ${\displaystyle \int _{x=0}^{1}\left(\int _{y=0}^{1}{\frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}}\,{\text{d}}y\right)\,{\text{d}}x={\frac{\pi }{4}}}$
>
> and ${\displaystyle \int _{y=0}^{1}\left(\int _{x=0}^{1}{\frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}}\,{\text{d}}x\right)\,{\text{d}}y=-{\frac{\pi }{4}}}$
>
> have different values. The corresponding double integral does not
>   converge absolutely (in other words the integral of the absolute value
>   is not finite):
>
> ${\displaystyle \int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1}\left|{\frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}}\right|\,{\text{d}}y\,{\text{d}}x=\infty.}$

Comment: Exactly. In your case you are integrating $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}\,\frac{x}{x+y}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, also text books should include these failed cases too rather than blindly writing "Fubini's theorem holds everytime there is a constant limit". It can create a lot of confusion when you run into questions like this.